# alert gives [object NodeList]

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a function in Javascript & jQuery .

```
dynamic_link = $j('#dynamic_link_add_btn').parent().parent().parent().parent()
                  .children('tbody').html();


function add_tier (t,html_handle){
     alert(html_handle);
     $j(t).parent().parent().parent().parent()
          .children('tbody').append(html_handle);
}
```

It is called by `onclick="add_tier(this,dynamic_link)"`:

```
<td class="a-right" colspan="4">
    <button class="scalable add" type="button" id="dynamic_link_add_btn" onclick="add_tier(this,dynamic_link)">
        <span>Add Extra Links</span>
    </button>
</td>
```

#### What is it?

Handles dynamic form fields (appending HTML, to be more precise).

#### How should it work?

It should add the HTML it gets from the `dynamic_link` variable to the designated place.
It works fine with other rows.
Rows have multiple input boxes and checkboxes.

#### What it does right now?

The alert gives out `[object NodeList]`.

#### What I have tried till now?

Iterated the `NodeList`. It doesn't return the HTML (I am not sure that it even does that task).

**NOTE:** The form is really a big one. There are many `dynamic_link` type variables which stores HTML. I have also compared character by character between the working and the not working LOC.

---

**Edit**: `$j` is just the `$` of jQuery. It's been defined with jQuery.noConflict.

Comment: Add html from the variable "dynamic_link"[it has the HTML, I alerted it] to a table. Managing Dynamic Forms Fields.

Comment: You shouldn't use alerts for debugging precisely because of this kind of thing. Use Chrome', Safari's, or Firebug's javascript console and log `dynamic_link` to there to see what you get.

Comment: @maxedison Will try that out. Thanks. Will let you guys know what I get.

Comment: Read the formatting FAQ please. You've been here for 9 months, yet this question still looked horrid before I fixed it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry for it. Was extremely impatient, Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you can use `jQuery` instaed of `$j` . that way you don't need to add `jQuery.noConflict`

then another point

instead of using

```
dynamic_link = $j('#dynamic_link_add_btn').parent().parent().parent().parent().children('tbody').html();
```

very easily you can use

```
dynamic_link = jQuery('#dynamic_link_add_btn').parents('.class_name').children('tbody').html();
```

class_name is the class name of your `parent` element that you want to select.

then you can try

```
jQuery('#dynamic_link_add_btn').live('click',function(){

var dynamic_link = jQuery(this).parents('.class_name').children('tbody').html();

      alert(dynamic_link);
      jQuery(this).parents('.class_name').children('tbody').append(dynamic_link);

});
```

to give a specific solution , you should post your HTML

Comment: Well, if you have another library which uses `$`, then you have to call `jQuery.conflict` to release `$` again...

Comment: @kanishka , using $j or jQuery is no issue issue. It works seamlessly throughout.

Comment: @turtle55 i know that is not an issue

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya just 2 mins, let me try live().

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya, How could i pass "dynamic_link" using live. It depends on the row. Now I remember why I didn't use .live(), because, assuming the code is working with live, and I have 1 <input>, I click on ADD, I get one more <input>, ADD again, I get 4 inputs. Did you get the logic?

Comment: @turtle55 yes i get it . like in my code you can generate dynamic_link , inside the function